# Setting up LAMP with CentOS 6.x

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I am having errors setting up my webserver on my vps. At the moment I have followed this tutorial: https://www.howtoforge.com/apache_php_mysql_on_centos_6.5_lamp

I am stuck on the `/etc/init.d/httpd start` part. When I run this command, I get the following output:

```
[root@localhost conf]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: [Mon Feb 23 21:27:02 2015] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts 
[FAILED]
```

And there is no more output. Prior to this I was getting this error:

```
[root@localhost etc]# /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully 
qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName [FAILED]
```

I googled and managed to get this error to disappear by editting `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` - I simply uncommented the `ServerName` variable and changed the value to localhost. So it looks like:

`ServerName localhost` - In my mind this makes sense since localhost is the external ip server anyways. [NOTE]: Even if I change it to `ServerName <external-ip>` I still get the same output when restarting httpd.

Can anyone help me get past this step? I've been googling for about 1-2 hours. Can't find anything. Anyone had the same error and mind pointing me in the right direction?

**UPDATE 1:**

cat /var/log/httpd/error_log

The output is basically normally operation until it reaches this point at which it just spams the rest of the log with it

`(2)No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file`
`/srv/www/java-applet/logs/error.log - Unable to open logs`

So I guess the error occurs since it cannot find the specified log file? Where can I change this? Why is this even occurring if I have a default installation of httpd?

**Update 2:**

Nevermind, I just solved it by making the directory that it said it was missing. Lame...

Comment: What is the error log saying should be in /var/log/httpd/error.log or something very similar in that directory.  I don't think your issue "NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts" that is just a warning... there is something else failing.

Comment: looks like a log file for a java applet... what else have you installed other than Apache, PHP and MySQL